# Add "/path/" in the middle of an URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, url, split

How can I effectively add a "path" to the middle of an URL in JavaScript?

I want to add **embed** to an URL, so the URL `https://blog.com/post/123` will end up looking like this `https://blog.com/embed/post/123`?

Cheers

Comment: You must have read this before [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I totally get this question just by the title, don't know where all the hate is coming from

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `<a>` and set the `href` property. Then prepend `embed` to the pathname and use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to get the whole URL.

```js
let element = document.createElement('a');
element.href = 'https://blog.com/post/123';
element.pathname = 'embed' + element.pathname;
console.log(element.toString());
```

Comment: this is a cool approach, but support for `pathname` etc is still kind of shaky across browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, if the path is just a string

```js
var path = "https://blog.com/post/123";
var withEmbed = path.replace(/\/post\//,'/embed/post/');
console.log(withEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

```
function addEmbed(location) {
    return location.protocol + '//' + location.host +
        '/embed' + location.pathname;
}

var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = 'https://blog.com/post/123';

var embed = addEmbed(url);
console.log(embed);  // "https://blog.com/embed/post/123"
```

Example:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXxvaq

Answer (score 0):

The way i would do it, is to pass by ref/value the original URL and the text you wan to add, into a function. It then removes the "https://" (if necessary), splits the url at the first "/" and saves each part as a var. Finally it puts it all back together and outputs it to a

on the html page.
This doesnt have to be outputted in this way, it could be saved as a global variable and then used in a link (but i didn't know what your plan was so i outputted it) :)

```
function addToURL(URL, add) {
    URL = URL.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//, '');
    var part1 = URL.substring(0, URL.indexOf("/") + 1);
    var part2 = URL.substring(URL.indexOf("/"), URL.length);
    var result = "https://" + part1 + add + part2;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Here's the example I made: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJBwZp

Hope this helps :P